# Configure session timeout in Grails Spring Security Core plugin, without modifying 'War'

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I would like to configure session timeout in Grails 2.3.11 with Spring Security Core plugin. But I don't want to touch it's war(output) file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend installing the `runtime ':webxml:1.4.1'` plugin, then you can create a file called `YOUR-APP/grails-app/conf/WebXmlConfig.groovy`:

```
webxml {
  sessionConfig.sessionTimeout = System.getProperty( 'SESSION_TIMEOUT' ) ?: System.getenv( 'SESSION_TIMEOUT' ) ?: 30
}
```

When the .war is deployed, you can set the system variable to the desired value